# Kentia Palm Leaves drying / yellowing / browning

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, kentia

I had this palm for a couple years now and about a year ago it lost a few small bottom leaves...but now it's suddenly loosing more and all tips are drying/browning (even on the biggest, newest leaves). I just cut off one leaf and now two / three more are on its way out. I'm not quite sure if I'm over or underwatering (but I have been paying attention to the soil being dry on top when watering and the drainage seems pretty good). Any idea what might be off and how I can save it?

Thank you for any advice in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]